# navigating from one qml page to another in cascades blackberry 10

Tags: listview, navigation, blackberry-10

I'm developing one blackberry 10 application.
I've coded the first page in **main.qml** which contains buttons and lables, etc. And this page doesn't contain any navigation or tabbed pane.

**Now when the user clicks on the button in the main.qml page, I have to show the second page i.e. cities.qml which shows some cities in the list view with header.
All cities are static data only. So how should i pass this data i.e collection of cities to second page and assign to list view.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points here: navigation, and listview usage:

1.) Navigation: You can either use a `NavigationPane`, which correspond to your needs, as I guess the user can go back from your second screen to the first one, or a `Sheet` to display your data. The `NavigationPane` seems to be the best here.

2.) Listview: To display data in a list, you need to provide the list a `DataModel`. If you have static data only, you can probably use something like a [`QAbstractListModel`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qabstractlistmodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have static data and want display them in a listview, you can use XmlDataModel.

[Check out the ListView developer site](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__listview.html) and their example:

QML:

```
Page {
content: Container {
    background: Color.White
    ListView {
        rootIndexPath: [1]
        dataModel: XmlDataModel { source: "model.xml" }
    }
}
```

}

XML:

```
<model>
<header title="North America">
  <item title="Toronto" />
  <item title="New York" />
</header>
<header title="Europe">
<item title="Copenhagen" />
  <item title="Malmo" />
 </header>
```